# Mageto2 how to remove index.php in url?

Tags: php, apache, magento

I have installed M242 on local. Docroot is `/pub`. All page show 404 except home page. I just realize that url must included `index.php` to work properly. How can i remove `index.php` in url? The content of `.htaccess` file is as default. Sorry, i cannot post it because limit characters in post

this is my demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn7hc.jpg

my system:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
Apache 2.4.41
Magento 2.4.2
PHP7.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause after i have hard took look into the config. The reason is the site config is not allow override then `.htaccess` not work properly.
I just run `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mm.conf` (mm.conf is apache2 site config, you can replace it to your site conf) in terminal and update it's content

Before:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mm.test
    ServerAlias mm.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mm/pub
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mm.test
    ServerAlias mm.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mm/pub
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/mm/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```